# SQL not exists in another table, but count is higher than 3 in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables that have profiles and list of photos (in the `photo` table) for each profile. I also have a `service` table and a `used` table, I want a query that would return the profile id which does not belong in the used service and also has more than 3 photos in the `photo` table

The `profile` table

```
CREATE TABLE public.profile
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('profile_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    birthday timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT profile_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The `photo` table

```
CREATE TABLE public.photo
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('photo_id_seq'::regclass),
    image bytea NOT NULL,
    image_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    order_count smallint NOT NULL,
    profile_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT photo_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT photo_profile_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
        REFERENCES public.profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

the `service` table

```
CREATE TABLE public.service
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('service_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT service_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the `used` table

```
CREATE TABLE public.used
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('used_id_seq'::regclass),
    service_id bigint NOT NULL,
    profile_id bigint NOT NULL,
    insert_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT used_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT used_profile_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
        REFERENCES public.profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT used_service_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
        REFERENCES public.service (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use exists and not exists

```
     select p.* from profile p
     where exists ( select 1 from photo ph where ph.profile_id =p.id
                                           having count (distinct image_id )=3
                   )
    and not exists ( select 1 from used u where u.profile_id =p.id)
```

Comment: It's super super slow. I assume I need to add indexes to my tables. On which columns do I need indexes?

Comment: @Arya id of profile  table profile_id of photo  and used table but i think for making index of profile_id of used and photo you need composite index

Comment: super fast now!

Comment: There is just one thing that I think need changing. The last part `select 1 from used u where u.profile_id =p.id` I changed to `SELECT 1 FROM used u WHERE u.service_id = 1` because I don't want it used for the service id that has 1. But now it returns no rows.  Here is the full SQL https://pastebin.com/8EQhW1qf

Comment: @Arya let me check it

Comment: @Arya you have to use condition where u.profile_id =p.id and u.service_id <>1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190564/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-arya).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
select p.profile_id
from photo p
where not exists (select 1
                  from used u
                  where u.profile_id = p.profile_id
                 )
group by p.profile_id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

If you just need the `profile_id`, then the `profiles` table is not needed.